# sending axios response to render page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, axios

I am requesting data from an external api using axios and I wish to use the response in my rendered page, my code is as follows:

```
//This is from my controller which is required in my main routes
exports.recordBySlug = async (req, res, next) => {
    const record = await Record.findOne({ slug: req.params.slug });
    if(!record) return next();

    const url = API_URL

    axios
        .get(url)
        .then(res => {
            const album = res.data.album;
            console.log(album)
        })
        .catch(console.error);

    res.render('record', { album })
};
```

I am receiving the response in the console (from `console.log(album)`) when I refresh the 'record' page exactly as I hoped, however i want to the use this data in my record view page (using pug) but I get a "ReferenceError: album is not defined"

I think I may need to use an await but not sure I am doing it right. I am hoping I am close to the solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just move the call to `render` to inside the callback:

```
axios
    .get(url)
    .then(res => {
        const album = res.data.album;
        console.log(album);
        res.render('record', { album })
    })
    .catch(next);
```

If you want to use `await` to hide the Promise it would be something like this:

```
try {
    const res = await axios.get(url);
    const album = res.data.album;

    console.log(album);
    res.render('record', { album });
}
catch (err) {
    next(err);
}
```

Not sure if there's a way to get rid of the `try`/`catch`, which makes it look untidy to me.